# Are there any drawings showing the routes the three main companies followed in chapter two of the Return of the King?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, map

Are there any drawings showing the routes that the three companies: Théoden, The Grey Company, Aragorn and Halbarad followed in the events in chapter 2, The Passing of the Grey Company, Lord of the Rings. I'm looking for a map of Middle Earth with the three routes drawn and labeled.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/OU2MNpL.gif

Comment: https://external-preview.redd.it/UsKadlb2znNx0l4VhHQIczXdyF91Ia9kvBFiAdYBOHY.jpg?auto=webp&s=7b6291c49d28bffd921dd6fb034d84b05f00ffdf

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bp0tOJCmDyY

Comment: http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Grey_Company this, I think

Comment: Go ahead and buy a copy of Karen Wynn Fonstad's _[Atlas of Middle-Earth](https://www.thriftbooks.com/w/the-atlas-of-middle-earth_jrr-tolkien_karen-wynn-fonstad/283058/item/4428913/)_.

Comment: @Valorum The youtube link appears to have an inaccuracy, in that Gandalf the White splits off from Aragorn, Legolas and Gimli when they head to the Hornburg, and heads of to marshal Eomer &Co. before rejoining them. It's a quibble, I know, but that's what SFF is for, yes? :D

Comment: @Lexible - A YouTube video? Inaccurate? I'll notify the Internet Police immediately ;-)

Comment: @Lexible --- You mean of course Erkenbrand of Westfold, not Eomer.

Comment: @IanThompson Oh! Yes! Yes, I meant Erkenbrand. :D

Comment: @IanThompson quibbleception!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *The Atlas of Middle-earth* by Karen Wynn Fonstad has two maps that address this.

**The Battle of the Pelennor Fields - TO THE BATTLE** (page 132)

[image: Ha! Good luck writing an alt text for this.]

**Pathways - DUNHARROW TO THE MORANNON** (pages 168-169)

[image: Ha! Good luck writing an alt text for this.]

The book also has a few pages of text explaining these maps and how they relate to the book, but it's too much to quote here.